# What are the different nuances of these expressions?

Tags: grammar

I am not a native speaker, could you enlighten me on the different nuances these expressions convey? Are all of them grammatical?

**To all women**

**To all women of the World**

**To all women in the World**

**To all the women of the World**

**To all the women in the World**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes (addresses women everywhere or women who are in a group)
2. Yes ("of the world" means someone who is experienced, educated, and 'worldly')
3. Yes (also addresses women everywhere---they're not literally "inside the world" but they inhabit it)
4. Same as #2
5. Same as #3

Comment: So #1, #3 and #5 are interchangeable? Could you think of a real life situation where only one could work?

Comment: I probably wouldn't use it in everyday talk, however if I were giving a speech (let's say to a women's empowerment group) then I'd probably say something like `To all women of the World...we are empowering.`